# Postgres. Insert multiple rows which don`t exist

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have pairs like `(<first_value>, <second_value>)` and I have table with following structure:

```
_____________________________________
| id | first_column | second_column |
```

I need to insert all pairs which do not exist already.
I think that I need something like `INSERT IF NOT EXIST` but for every pair.

I try use this code:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name>(<first_column>, <second_column>) 
VALUES (CASE 
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM <table_name>
                WHERE <first_column> = <pair_1_value_1> AND <second_column> = <pair_1_value_2>
            ) THEN (<pair_1_value_1>, <pair_1_value_2>) 
    
            WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                SELECT 1 
                FROM <table_name>
                WHERE <first_column> = <pair_2_value_1> AND <second_column> = <pair_2_value_2>
            ) THEN (<pair_2_value_1>, <pair_2_value_2>) 

            .....

         END
);
```

But I get this error: `INSERT has more target columns than expressions`. Also, I thought it wouldn't work because it would only insert the one line that first passes the condition. As a `if - elif - else` operators in other programing languages

Comment: I guess,you can read in PostgreSQL-manual about ON CONFLICT clause

Comment: Where those all pairs should come from?

Comment: @Sergey. But I do not have conflict. First and second values is not unique in table. But I need unique pairs. (1, 1) (2,1) or (1, 1) (1,2)  - Okay. (1,1) (1,1) - Not okay

Comment: @Serg pairs from python dict. And I wouldn't want to query all the pairs first, check uniqueness through python, and then add unique ones. I would like to do everything in sql

Comment: Is (first_column, second_column)  a unique key in the table? Then you can `insert .. on conflict do nothing`

Comment: @Serg. No. Look at the third comment. The values in the table are not unique. Only id is unique. But it is pairs of values that must be unique.

Comment: If they need to be unique then make them unique. Add a `UNIQUE` index on `(first_column, second_column)`, then you can use `ON CONFLICT`.

Comment: `<table_name>(<first_column>, <second_column>)` BTW: please don't use meta-syntax or pseudocode. Use actual code, with actual names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **both** your conditions are false, your query attempts to insert zero values into two columns. That is not going to fit. In that case you need to insert zero **rows** with two columns.

There is no `IF` in SQL; don't try to emulate it. There is `WHERE` :

---

```
CREATE TABLE omg
        ( first_column text
        , second_column text
        , PRIMARY KEY (first_column, second_column)
        );

WITH wtf (one,two) AS (
        VALUES ( 'aa', 'ab')
             , ( 'ba', 'bb')
        )
INSERT INTO omg(first_column, second_column)
SELECT one, two
FROM wtf w
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT*
        FROM omg nx
        WHERE nx.first_column = w.one
        AND nx.second_column = w.two
        )
        ;
```

---

In your actual code it is probably better to:

- create a temp table (`CREATE TEMP TABLE wtf as SELECT * FROM omg where 0=1`)
- insert **all** the values (from your Python code) into this temp table
- select (**distinct**) from this temp table (instead of from the `wtf` CTE)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `MERGE` statement do exactly what you need?
This example seems to work as you describe, at least to me:

```
CREATE TABLE tgt (a,b) AS (
            SELECT 'A','A'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'B','B'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'C','C'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'D','D'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'E','E'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'F','F'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'G','G'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'H','H'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'I','I'
  UNION ALL SELECT 'J','J'
)
;
-- out CREATE TABLE
MERGE INTO tgt
USING (
  SELECT 'A','A' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'K','K' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L','L'
) src(a,b)
  ON src.a=tgt.a
 AND src.b=tgt.b
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT VALUES (src.a,src.b)
;
-- out  OUTPUT 
-- out --------
-- out       2
SELECT * FROM tgt;
-- out  a | b 
-- out ---+---
-- out  A | A
-- out  B | B
-- out  C | C
-- out  D | D
-- out  E | E
-- out  F | F
-- out  G | G
-- out  H | H
-- out  I | I
-- out  J | J
-- out  K | K
-- out  L | L
```